# preg match wrong result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this string:

```
a[0]=a[27%a.length];
```

and this pattern

```
([a-z])+\[(\S)+\]\=([a-z])+\[+(.*?)+\%+([a-z])+\.length
```

Preg match array is this one:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "a[0]=a[27%a.length"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

Why is the element 4 empty instead of holding the **27**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's one "+" too many. This regex seems to work as you would expect:

`([a-z])+\[(\S)+\]\=([a-z])+\[+(.*?)\%+([a-z])+\.length`

The following is even cleaner, and it matches the input string:

`([a-z])+\[(\S)+\]\=([a-z])+\[(.*?)\%([a-z])+\.length`

The difference is that I removed the unnecessary "+" after the squared brackets ("+" means "one or more", while there should be only **one** bracket in each position).

For an explanation, please refer to regex101, which has a nice formatting for the various parts of the expression: http://regex101.com/r/iB6nH1

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `(.*?)+`, the matched part will be replaced by empty string at end.

Remove that `+` then you will get `27` in the match part.

```
php > preg_match('/([a-z])+\[(\S)+\]\=([a-z])+\[+(.*?)\%+([a-z])+\.length/', $str, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "a[0]=a[27%a.length"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "27"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```